# Could not install the application iPad however it works in iPhone in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: ipad, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to run my Xamarin.Form application in iPad but it doesn't work. App is terminate. However it is working fine with iPhone and all simulators.

Here is error. Can anybody please suggest?

> error MT1006: Could not install the application
>   '/Users/MyUserName/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyProject.iOS/2d4c7284723da8be52aedbd4024e4fcc/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/ipad7.3-11.0.2/MyProject.app'
>   on the device 'My iPad pro': Your application failed code-signing
>   checks.  Check your certificates, provisioning profiles, and bundle
>   ids.   Probably your device is not part of the selected provisioning
>   profile (error: 0xe8008015).

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

> Check your certificates, provisioning profiles, and bundle ids. Probably your device is not part of the selected provisioning profile

When testing your app and wanting to run it on a physical device you will have to register each device in a so-called provisioning profile. Go into the Apple Developer Portal, find the provisioning profile associated to your app and add your iPad to this profile.

Then make sure that the new provisioning profile is downloaded to the machine where you create the build from and create a new build. You should then be able to run it on your iPad.

For a more detailed description, please refer to the [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/deploy-test/publishing-to-the-app-store/profiles).

Comment: Okay but I think it should work because it is working fine with iPhone. If profile is required, I must add profile(certificate) for iPhone. Can you please explain me? I am new here.

Comment: I'm not sure how you managed that then. Maybe it's worth having a look at the automatic provisioning if you're using Visual Studio for Mac

Comment: Sure, I will check. I am using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise with Windows 10. Can you please suggest me where should I check this setting? Is it existing in my project or in Visual Studio tool or anywhere else? Please guide

Comment: This functionality is not implemented in Visual Studio on Windows yet, I think it will be included in a version in the nearby future.

Comment: Okay, that means I will not be able to test my application in iPad until I upgrade development environment to VS + Mac or Microsoft come up with this feature?

Comment: No, you can still generate the right profile manually. Just follow the documentation.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I will try to generate profile for iPad. I hope this change will not effect my iPhone testing compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

**Visual Studio on Windows** has the automatic provisioning feature in **preview** (called 15.7) right now (preview 3 released today): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-preview-relnotes#xamarin-provisioning.
I recommend you try that, it should help you automatically add your iPad to the relevant provisioning profile.

Otherwise you have a couple other options:

1. Follow [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/automatic-provisioning) to use automatic provisioning on Visual Studio for Mac. It will take care of adding the device to your provisioning profile.
2. Register the device manually using [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning?tabs=vsmac).
3. Use Xcode on the Mac. Create a new iPad template and deploy it to the device.